# GPS coordinate to pixel on map which is referenced with 3 points

Tags: python, gps, coordinates

I'm having image of map which is calibrated to lat and lon coordinates with 3 points.

Let's say
P1 = [lat1, lon1, x1, y1]
P2 = [lat2, lon2, x2, y2]
P3 = [lat3, lon3, x3, y3]

where lat and lon are cooridnates in real world, x and y are corresponding pixels in the map image.

And then I have measured GPS coordiante (lat, lon) that I would need to plot on the image. So I would need to find the pixel (x, y) for it.

How can I calcualte the pixel for the measured coordinate?

The area of the map is relatively small (max ~10km) so I assume we can assume earth being flat.

I'm working on python

Comment: looks difficult, one needs to have good understanding of geodesics for it

Comment: why don't  just use https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html

Comment: Because I want to understand how this is possible to implement. And I want to use my own image of the map